# crear URL para redireccionar a una aplicaion movil

Tags: ionic2, app

como se crea una URL para redireccionar a una aplicaion movil. La url es enviada a gmail o hotmail. Pero como se crea. He buscando en internet pero ninguna funciona y otras son muy enredadas. La url la estoy creando desde una api de php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te refieres a esto?

```
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="My App" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="my-app://path" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="apple-app-id" />

<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="My App">
<meta property="al:android:url" content="my-app://path">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="google-app-package">
```

http://christopher5106.github.io/mobile/2015/03/26/web-redirection-to-mobile-web-or-app-with-a-modal-box.html

Comment: Gracias . Aceptare la respuesta. No especifique que era para hacerlo en ionic.

Comment: Entonces adjunto este enlace por las dudas (?) http://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/